How do I fetch consumed size of all Azure storage accounts in a tenant
I have a requirement to fetch consumed data in all storage accounts in a tenant for creating a dashboard.
I might need a PowerShell script where we can get this data into a csv file ! This is to display the date into our own dashboard.

Is the below approach worked for you?

sorry it took sometime to come back. yes the given script worked for me with slight changes to the code. Many thanks @Venkatesan


How do I fetch consumed size of all Azure storage accounts in a tenant?

You can use the below PowerShell script to get the used capacity (consumed size) of all Azure Storage accounts in MB.
Script:
Connect-AzAccount -Tenant 'xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx'

$sub = Get-AzSubscription | select Name

$sub | foreach { 
    Set-AzContext -SubscriptionId $_.Name

    $RGs = Get-AzResourceGroup | select ResourceGroupName
    $results = @()

    $RGs | foreach {
        $CurrentRG = $_.ResourceGroupName
        $StorageAccounts = Get-AzStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName $CurrentRG | select StorageAccountName
        Write-Host "Processing storage accounts in resource group $CurrentRG..."
        $StorageAccounts | foreach {
            $StorageAccount = $_.StorageAccountName
            $CurrentSAID = (Get-AzStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName $CurrentRG -AccountName $StorageAccount).Id
            $usedCapacity = (Get-AzMetric -ResourceId $CurrentSAID -MetricName "UsedCapacity" -WarningAction SilentlyContinue).Data
            $usedCapacityInMB = $usedCapacity.Average / 1024 / 1024
            $results += [PSCustomObject]@{
                StorageAccountName = $StorageAccount
                UsedCapacityInMB = $usedCapacityInMB
                ResourceGroupName = $CurrentRG
                Subscription = $_.Name
            }
        }
        Write-Host "Finished processing storage accounts in resource group $CurrentRG."
    }

    $results | Export-Csv -Path "output_$($_.Name).csv" -NoTypeInformation
}

Output:

Reference:
Get-AzMetric (Az.Monitor) | Microsoft Learn

Since the question is about fetching all storage accounts for a tenant (which means multiple subscriptions), you may want to modify your script to fetch all subscriptions first and then looping over them to get all storage accounts.

Thanks for the inputs @GauravMantri Updated in answer.
